# Detecting proxy server from client side

Tags: proxy, tcpip

I suspect my ISP is using a proxy server, though I cannot prove it.
The only evidence I've got is that incoming packets have a very high TTL > 254.

Is there a way to check it out, without calling my ISP (I don't trust the call-center to have the right answer for that kind of question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Proxy Test](http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test). A quote from the page:

> The Lagado Proxy Test shows details of
> any proxy servers you are using. It is
> especially useful to expose
> transparent proxies. These are proxies
> inserted between your browser and the
> web, typically by your ISP, and often
> without you knowing.